# USB HID report error (intentional?) prevents joydev from correctly calculating axes values

Tags: drivers, usb, hid

Thrustmaster T.Flight 4 would only partially work with `jstest` (Z axis, throttle and an additional axis on the throttle handle) so I decided to try and fix it.

I dumped hidraw data and learned that those axes do indeed work, but when I compared their position in the data packet with the decoded HID report - I think the report is incorrectly presenting the data. Or I don't understand how to properly read the report, or I miscounted the data.
Their manual says that it is of utmost importance to install the driver if the joystick is to be used with PC Windows.
I am *assuming* their driver keeps rewriting the values from `Vendor defined` regions into the correct `Usage` regions.

I have already half-written a HID userspace "driver" that parses out values, but I'm thinking - if I could somehow just copy the bytes from vendor regions into where the report claims they are - I could leave all the heavy lifting to `joydev` and just fix this little sh** of a probably intentional bug, either because of PS4 compatibility or because its useful to force windows people to install and use the driver.

Questions:

- Is this the correct idea to push forward?
- If yes, how could I accomplish this?
- If no, what is a better way to continue forward? I am assuming, somehow get `joydev` to recognize my userspace driver, but I'm dabbling in unknown waters here, so please - any guidance is useful.

This is an example of a data packet:

```
    1 80 80 80 80 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 80 0 80 80 5c ff 80 0 0 80 80 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Ignoring the counter (`1`), first two bytes are correctly set to neutral position for axes `X` and `Y`. However, the next two bytes (supposedly `Z` and `Rz`) do not change values no matter what I push or press.

Thing is, if you look down the stream, where bytes `5c` and `ff` are, *those* are in vendor specific areas, and they are the throttle axis and an additional analog button axis. Adjacent to them is the `Z` axis (value `80`), ie. the twist on the joystick.

This is the report:

```
// 0x05, 0x01,                    // Usage Page (Generic Desktop)        0
// 0x09, 0x05,                    // Usage (Game Pad)                    2
// 0xa1, 0x01,                    // Collection (Application)            4
// 0x85, 0x01,                    //  Report ID (1)                      6
// 0x09, 0x30,                    //  Usage (X)                          8
// 0x09, 0x31,                    //  Usage (Y)                          10
// 0x09, 0x32,                    //  Usage (Z)                          12
// 0x09, 0x35,                    //  Usage (Rz)                         14
// 0x15, 0x00,                    //  Logical Minimum (0)                16
// 0x26, 0xff, 0x00,              //  Logical Maximum (255)              18
// 0x75, 0x08,                    //  Report Size (8)                    21
// 0x95, 0x04,                    //  Report Count (4)                   23
// 0x81, 0x02,                    //  Input (Data,Var,Abs)               25
// 0x09, 0x39,                    //  Usage (Hat switch)                 27
// 0x15, 0x00,                    //  Logical Minimum (0)                29
// 0x25, 0x07,                    //  Logical Maximum (7)                31
// 0x35, 0x00,                    //  Physical Minimum (0)               33
// 0x46, 0x3b, 0x01,              //  Physical Maximum (315)             35
// 0x65, 0x14,                    //  Unit (Degrees,EngRotation)         38
// 0x75, 0x04,                    //  Report Size (4)                    40
// 0x95, 0x01,                    //  Report Count (1)                   42
// 0x81, 0x42,                    //  Input (Data,Var,Abs,Null)          44
// 0x65, 0x00,                    //  Unit (None)                        46
// 0x05, 0x09,                    //  Usage Page (Button)                48
// 0x19, 0x01,                    //  Usage Minimum (1)                  50
// 0x29, 0x0e,                    //  Usage Maximum (14)                 52
// 0x15, 0x00,                    //  Logical Minimum (0)                54
// 0x25, 0x01,                    //  Logical Maximum (1)                56
// 0x75, 0x01,                    //  Report Size (1)                    58
// 0x95, 0x0e,                    //  Report Count (14)                  60
// 0x81, 0x02,                    //  Input (Data,Var,Abs)               62
// 0x06, 0x00, 0xff,              //  Usage Page (Vendor Defined Page 1) 64
// 0x09, 0x20,                    //  Usage (Vendor Usage 0x20)          67
// 0x75, 0x06,                    //  Report Size (6)                    69
// 0x95, 0x01,                    //  Report Count (1)                   71
// 0x81, 0x02,                    //  Input (Data,Var,Abs)               73
// 0x05, 0x01,                    //  Usage Page (Generic Desktop)       75
// 0x09, 0x33,                    //  Usage (Rx)                         77
// 0x09, 0x34,                    //  Usage (Ry)                         79
// 0x15, 0x00,                    //  Logical Minimum (0)                81
// 0x26, 0xff, 0x00,              //  Logical Maximum (255)              83
// 0x75, 0x08,                    //  Report Size (8)                    86
// 0x95, 0x02,                    //  Report Count (2)                   88
// 0x81, 0x02,                    //  Input (Data,Var,Abs)               90
// 0x06, 0x00, 0xff,              //  Usage Page (Vendor Defined Page 1) 92
// 0x09, 0x21,                    //  Usage (Vendor Usage 0x21)          95
// 0x95, 0x36,                    //  Report Count (54)                  97
// 0x81, 0x02,                    //  Input (Data,Var,Abs)               99
// 0x85, 0x05,                    //  Report ID (5)                      101
// 0x09, 0x22,                    //  Usage (Vendor Usage 0x22)          103
// 0x95, 0x1f,                    //  Report Count (31)                  105
// 0x91, 0x02,                    //  Output (Data,Var,Abs)              107
// 0x85, 0x03,                    //  Report ID (3)                      109
// 0x0a, 0x21, 0x27,              //  Usage (Vendor Usage 0x2721)        111
// 0x95, 0x2f,                    //  Report Count (47)                  114
// 0xb1, 0x02,                    //  Feature (Data,Var,Abs)             116
// 0xc0,                          // End Collection                      118
// 0x06, 0xf0, 0xff,              // Usage Page (Vendor Usage Page 0xfff0) 119
// 0x09, 0x40,                    // Usage (Vendor Usage 0x40)           122
// 0xa1, 0x01,                    // Collection (Application)            124
// 0x85, 0xf0,                    //  Report ID (240)                    126
// 0x09, 0x47,                    //  Usage (Vendor Usage 0x47)          128
// 0x95, 0x3f,                    //  Report Count (63)                  130
// 0xb1, 0x02,                    //  Feature (Data,Var,Abs)             132
// 0x85, 0xf1,                    //  Report ID (241)                    134
// 0x09, 0x48,                    //  Usage (Vendor Usage 0x48)          136
// 0x95, 0x3f,                    //  Report Count (63)                  138
// 0xb1, 0x02,                    //  Feature (Data,Var,Abs)             140
// 0x85, 0xf2,                    //  Report ID (242)                    142
// 0x09, 0x49,                    //  Usage (Vendor Usage 0x49)          144
// 0x95, 0x0f,                    //  Report Count (15)                  146
// 0xb1, 0x02,                    //  Feature (Data,Var,Abs)             148
// 0x85, 0xf3,                    //  Report ID (243)                    150
// 0x0a, 0x01, 0x47,              //  Usage (Vendor Usage 0x4701)        152
// 0x95, 0x07,                    //  Report Count (7)                   155
// 0xb1, 0x02,                    //  Feature (Data,Var,Abs)             157
// 0xc0,                          // End Collection                      159
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a github repository of a person that already wrote a kernel module, that (I believe) patches a HID report to correctly point at the right bytes. I tested it and it works very well, so if you just want your hardware to work, here it is:

https://github.com/walterschell/tflight4